# How can I split a shower head with this fitting?

Tags: plumbing, shower, plumbing-fixture

I want to add a second shower head that splits off at the fitting for the current shower head (because my ceiling is low so I have to sit, and I want a shower head that sprays my lower body at the same time).

I can't do the easy thing, which would be to split it at the base and run two hoses from there, because the hose has to go through that hole (see photos).

How can I attach a second flexible-hose shower head?

[image: Shower head]

[image: Context of the hose]

Comment: This is not a very good advertisement for Illinois engineering program.

Comment: Definitely not a good school to learn home improvement best practices

Comment: Hey Josh. If you have found something else. I just ran across something that might work & added it to my answer just now.

Answer (score 1):

Most hand held shower hose/sprayer units utilize 1/2" pipe thread, aka 1/2"NPT (not all, some have a proprietary thread). You should be able to rig a tee to that mounting bracket (somehow, using hose clamps, velcro, ingenuity, etc.) using 1/2" PCV fittings.

You could make it so the hose supplies the fixed tee, then use an additional hose or other fixed mount to locate two heads wherever you want.

Be advised, PVC pipe fittings use a *tapered* thread, which seals by taper along with thread compound and/or teflon tape. Those shower hoses and heads that would have the same thread (1/2"NPT) would utilize a non-tapered thread which seals by use of a flat rubber or vinyl washer/gasket. Does this mean that they will not work with PVC fittings? No, it means they will seem to not thread in very far perhaps, and to get a seal you made need some combination of teflon tape and gaskets. It's an open-ended system so it should not be under any real pressure anyway. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I think the shower head cradle would be a problem. It's really just shopping around to find a Y, like for a garden hose. But, you'll need to also find a 2" or more straight pipe to thread above the Y so you can continue to use the cradle without issue.

I'm thinking you might luck-out in the toilet shut-off valve arena as they have the chromed male stubs. I don't remember noticing any shut-off Y's, but they must exist for Bidet setups. Of course, a plumbing supply store would be the best bet...bring the shower head with you for test fitting.

If you haven't found something else already. [**I ran across this online today**](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Homewerks-Worldwide-1-2-in-x-1-2-in-x-1-4-in-Brass-Extender-Tee-Carded-VETOEMB3C-Z/203444236) in Home Depot's shut-off valve search, **IF** the size & threads are right it might do the trick.